# How to fetch the value from td tag & show this value in a textbox in another page in php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have 2 pages `Manage.php` & `edit.php`
in `manage.php`, I have an `HTML` `table` created with *dynamic data* and cannot predict the *number of rows* in it. Each row has a *name column* , `edit button` & `delete button`.
What i want that when i click on any *edit* / *delete* button its corresponding value of name column
 should be displayed in `textbox` in `edit page` using php????
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jquery for this.

Try

```
$('.buttonclass').on('click', function () {
    var column_name= $(this).closest('tr').next().find('input').val();
});
```

Of course this assumes that the first column is the name column and is looking in to a  element. 
You can change it to `.find('td').html();`

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind primary key to the edit and delete button for this particular record, then you have to pass this id/name to the edit page and assign it to that text box. if you are passing only id then you can make select query for selecting name.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

i assume your list is in `manage.php`:
pass related id and get it into another page.

```
<a href="edit.php?id=1&mode=edit">Edit</a>
<a href="edit.php?id=1&mode=delete">Delete</a>
```

and in `edit.php :`

```
<?php
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$mode = $_REQUEST['mode'];
if($id !="")
{
  if($mode == "edit")
  {
    //fetch data using id and disply it into your textbox
  }
}
?>
```

and if you want additional security use [base64_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php)  and [base64_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php).
`example:`

```
<?php
$id = "1";
$encodeid = base64_encode($id);
?>
<a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $encodeid;?>&mode=edit">Edit</a>
```

and in second page

```
<?php
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$decodeid = base64_decode($id);
?>
```